# My program is printing value following the order of my .txt file and I don't want that to happen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, ipython

I want to prompt the user to input specific data from a text file(keys) so my dictionary can give the value for each of them.

It works like this:

```
fin=open('\\python34\\lib\\toys.txt')
toys = {}

for word in fin:
    x=fin.readline()
    x = word.replace("\n",",").split(",")
    a = x[0]
    b=x[1]
    toys[a]=str(b)
    i = input("Please enter the code:")
    if i in toys:
        print(i," is the code for a= ", toys[i],)
    else:
        print('Try again')
    if i == 'quit':
        break
```

but it prints 'try again' if I input a random key from my list. (which is the following:

D1,Tyrannasaurous

D2,Apatasauros

D3,Velociraptor

D4,Tricerotops

D5,Pterodactyl

T1,Diesel-Electric

T2,Steam Engine

T3,Box Car

T4,Tanker Car

T5,Caboose

B1,Baseball

B2,Basketball

B3,Football

B4,Softball

B5,Tennis Ball

B6,Vollyeball

B7,Rugby Ball

B8,Cricket Ball

B9,Medicine Ball

but if I do it in order it works. How can I fix this program so I can input any key at any time and it will still print its corresponding value?

Comment: `for word in fin:` followed by `x=fin.readline()`: you appear to step through the lines in your file (the for loop), followed immediately by reading another line of your file. And then you throw away the result of that next readline(). Is that correct?

Comment: Perhaps it's a good idea to do some standard debuggin, and print out word, x, a and b in your loop to see what's happening.

Comment: Yes it is. `x=fin.readline() ` reads each line and then ` x = word.replace("\n",",").split(",") ` separates the key from the value for my dictionary. @Evert

Comment: @Evert I tried by printing out each one outside the loop and it worked perfectly. I don't understand what the problem is, but thanks !!

Comment: Re: your first comment: there may be a misunderstanding, but `x = fin.readline()` will not read each line. The `for word in fin` line also read lines from your file, with the result that the first reads all even lines, and the second all odd lines.

Comment: Re: your second comment: why did you print them *outside* the loop? Inside the loop you'll see what's happening.

Comment: unrelated: you could use `r'\python34\lib\toys.txt'` (raw string literal) instead of `'\\python34\\lib\\toys.txt'`, to avoid escaping backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read in the whole file before prompting for your search term. So you'll need two loops -- one to get the whole data in, and a second loop to search through he data.

Here's what your updated code will look like. I replaced the file input with an array so that I could run it using a web tool:

```
fin=['D1,Tyrannasaurous','D2,Apatasauros','D3,Velociraptor' ]
toys = {}

for word in fin:
    x = word.replace("\n",",").split(",")
    a = x[0]
    b=x[1]
    toys[a]=str(b)

while 1:
    i = input("\nPlease enter the code:")
    if i in toys:
        print(i," is the code for a= ", toys[i],)
    else:
        print('\nTry again')
    if i == 'quit':
        break
```

Output here: https://repl.it/BVxh

Answer (score 0):

To read the file into dictionary:

```
with open('toys.txt') as file:
    toys = dict(line.strip().split(',') for line in file)
```

To print values corresponding to the input keys provided by a user from a command-line interactively until `quit` key is received:

```
for code in iter(lambda: input("Please enter the code:"), 'quit'):
    if code in toys:
        print(code, "is the code for toy:", toys[code])
    else:
        print(code, 'is not found. Try again')
```

It uses [two-argument `iter(func, sentinel)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter).